# Remove dates contained within other dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following rows:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (id int, name varchar(255), startdate datetime, enddate datetime)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'John', '2011-01-11 00:00:00.000','2011-01-11 00:01:10.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'John', '2011-01-11 00:00:20.000','2011-01-11 00:01:05.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 'John', '2011-01-11 00:01:40.000','2011-01-11 00:01:50.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4, 'Adam', '2011-01-11 00:00:40.000','2011-01-11 00:01:20.000')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(5, 'Adam', '2011-01-11 00:00:45.000','2011-01-11 00:01:15.000')

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

I am trying to remove records that have dates contained within other dates to obtain the following:

```
John 2011-01-11 00:00:00.000 2011-01-11 00:01:10.000
John 2011-01-11 00:01:40.000 2011-01-11 00:01:50.000
Adam 2011-01-11 00:00:40.000 2011-01-11 00:01:20.000
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this for a table of about 100K rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the desired result:

```
DELETE T1 FROM #TEMP T1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL FROM #TEMP T2
    WHERE   t1.id <> t2.id
    AND     t1.name = t2.name
    AND     t1.startdate >= t1.startdate
    AND     t1.enddate   <= t1.enddate
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

**Edit**: I've just noticed that there's one problem. If there are duplicates (same start- and enddate), both would be deleted (none with John's approach, even with only one equal date). So you need to take this into account:

```
DELETE T1 FROM #TEMP T1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL FROM #TEMP T2
    WHERE   t1.id <> t2.id
    AND     t1.name = t2.name
    AND     t1.startdate > t2.startdate
    AND     t1.enddate   < t2.enddate
    OR      t1.id <> t2.id
    AND     t1.name = t2.name
    AND     t1.startdate = t2.startdate
    AND     t1.enddate   < t2.enddate
    OR      t1.id <> t2.id
    AND     t1.name = t2.name
    AND     t1.startdate > t2.startdate
    AND     t1.enddate   = t2.enddate
    OR      t1.id > t2.id
    AND     t1.name = t2.name
    AND     t1.startdate = t2.startdate
    AND     t1.enddate   = t2.enddate
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I maybe missing something but I did put this record in the output?

Comment: @Legend: Edited my answer, it was my fault :)

Comment: Both John and Tim have nice queries. I actualy thought that the join would be faster but it is certainly not (I am not considering indexes). I loaded up a test table with  2.384.001 random of data and the EXIST version finished in 1:43 while I stopped the JOIN version after 10 minutes. The estimate executions plans are different and give the EXIST quit less of logical reads while the actual plans for the  2.384.001 records produced the same plan if one only takes into account the operators. The EXISTS can stop scanning after it founds a match which is a big advantage.

Comment: @buckley: Noticed that both queries have problems with duplicates, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE t1 FROM #TEMP t1
INNER JOIN #TEMP t2 ON t2.startdate < t1.startdate AND t1.enddate < t2.enddate
AND t1.name = t2.name
```

Results match